# Error while using Amazon .NET SDK

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I installed .NET SDK and in Visual Studio, selected New Project -> AWS -> Storage and Content Delivery -> AWS S3 Sample. Given below is my code.

```
using (client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client())
{
    ListBucketsResponse response = client.ListBuckets();
}
```

My app.config has 3 values:

```
<add key="AWSAccessKey" value="xxxx"/>
<add key="AWSSecretKey" value="xxxxxxxx"/>
<add key="AWSRegion" value="us-east-1"/>
```

I get following exception at the statement:

```
ListBucketsResponse response = client.ListBuckets();
```

**Exception**

The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

**Inner Exception**

The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Please help.

Comment: I think the exception message is very clear

Comment: @Matt, I saw the samples and there was not additional code. So I thought it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you figured this out yet, but I can confirm that your code is working 100% when I substitute my credentials instead.

If you are sure your credentials are correct, then make sure you have the newest .net sdk installed and try again - just tried it myself with version 2.0.15.1 available here:

http://sdk-for-net.amazonwebservices.com/latest/AWSToolsAndSDKForNet.msi

and it works as expected.